# Why height is not working with DropDownList in IE9 but work with Chrome and FF?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

Here's the code

```
select
{
 font-size: 9px; 
 color: Blue; 
 font-weight: bold;
 height: 30px;
}
```

Is there any reason it's not working with IE9.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like? Can you post a jsFiddle?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? My IE 9 displays it pretty much like Chrome does: http://jsfiddle.net/UAZYc/1/

Comment: I mean, for the Chrome and FF, the DDL become height while, for IE9, the DDL keeps the same height no matter the value of the height.

Comment: @Richard77 You should have this info in your question. But for me it's still allright: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1529612/ie9-height.png

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what kind of html-element you do this, but add display:block ; to it. 
That will do the trick for IE

Comment: I've added display block. No success

Answer (score 0):

Richard, when you tested your own code, was the render-mode quirks ?
I tested your code and the ONLY thing i added was the doctype and html tag like this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        SELECT {
        font-size: 9px; 
        color: Blue; 
        font-weight: bold;
        height: 30px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="">
            <option>Test data 1</option>
     </select>
</body>
</html>
```